# any way to make a json schema extend from a allOf?

Tags: jsonschema

I am quite new to json schema's and I'm not finding a way to do this.

We are being forced to use draft-4 as we want to use Visual Studio to edit these

We have a json object that has essentially two parts

Part 1

- a. tableId (string)

  or
- b. Schema (string) and a TableName (string)

Part 2

- a. ObjectA

  or
- b. ObjectB

Is there any elegent way to express this in json schema or am I going to have to declare each Object and type by name and create 4 seperate schemas referring to each piece and then essentially have an verbosely expanded version of a oneOf that is essentially "oneof":[{aa},{ab},{ba},{bb}]

---

UPDATED

I've tried the suggestions but I can't seem to get this to work

Attempt 1. allOf\oneOf

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
    "allOf": [
        {
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/directTableReference"
                },
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/tableIdObject"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/ObjectA"
                },
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/ObjectB"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "directTableReference": {
            "type": "object",
            "title": "schema directTableReference",
            "properties": {
                "schema": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "tableName": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "schema",
                "tableName"
            ]
        },
        "tableIdObject": {
            "type": "object",
            "title": "schema tableIdObject",
            "properties": {
                "tableId": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "tableId"
            ]
        },
        "ObjectA": {
            "type": "object",
            "title": "schema objectA",
            "properties": {
                "ObjectAName": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "ObjectAName"
            ]
        },
        "ObjectB": {
            "type": "object",
            "title": "schema objectB",
            "properties": {
                "ObjectBName": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "ObjectBName"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is incorrect but it is validated. I can see that it hasn't found ObjectAName to be ObjectA as it doesn't show the title in the hover over in visual studio code

```json
{
    "$schema": "./testSchema.json",
    "ObjectAName":"blah",
    "ObjectBName":"blah"
}
```

Attempt 2 - oneOf\allOf with all 4 combinations

Even this doesn't work

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
    "title": "testSchema",
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/directTableReference"
                },
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/ObjectA"
                }
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/tableIdObject"
                },
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/ObjectA"
                }
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/directTableReference"
                },
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/ObjectB"
                }
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/tableIdObject"
                },
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/ObjectB"
                }
            ],
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "directTableReference": {
            "type": "object",
            "title": "schema directTableReference",
            "properties": {
                "schema": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "tableName": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "schema",
                "tableName"
            ]
        },
        "tableIdObject": {
            "type": "object",
            "title": "schema tableIdObject",
            "properties": {
                "tableId": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "tableId"
            ]
        },
        "ObjectA": {
            "type": "object",
            "title": "schema objectA",
            "properties": {
                "ObjectAName": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "ObjectAName"
            ]
        },
        "ObjectB": {
            "type": "object",
            "title": "schema objectB",
            "properties": {
                "ObjectBName": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "ObjectBName"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is now seen as invalid and actually as the directTableReference Object

```json
{
    "tableId": "blah",
    "ObjectAName": "blah"
}
```

Struggling to see the point of allOf when it basically makes impossible objects, but surely I'm missing a trick here.

Is there no way to actually reuse these objects or is there no way to do this in draft-4. Does it help if I can go to draft-7?

Thanks for any help

Comment: the problem with my attempts was that I was not redeclaring the properties under each of the allOf/oneOf. rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you should be able to do that by combining `definitions` and `$ref` with `allOf`, `anyOf` and `oneOf`.

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html

The docs refer to `$defs`, but in draft4 that was called `definitions`.

So, something like:

```
definitions:
  tableId:
    ...
  Schema:
    ...
  ObjectA:
    ...
  ObjectB:
    ...
  ObjectC:
    ...
allOf:
  - anyOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/tableId'
    - allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/Schema'
      - $ref: '#/definitions/TableName'
  - anyOf:
    - allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/ObjectA'
      - $ref: '#/definitions/ObjectB'
      - $ref: '#/definitions/ObjectC'
    - allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/ObjectA'
      - $ref: '#/definitions/ObjectD'
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. You mention oneOf in the summary at the top but the example only uses anyOf and oneOf, is there a mistake in one?

Comment: thanks. the problem I found is that it was still allowing tableId as well as Schema and TableName so Part 1 allof doesn't work. I had to change it to slightly less elegant oneOf ( allOf ( 1a, 2a), allOf (1b, 2a)...) with additionalProperties set to false at each level to prevent that

Comment: I can't get this to work correctly at all. I will update the description

Comment: BTW I didn't use anyOf as you suggested in my examples as oneOf seemed to result in a stronger validation (I don't want multiple to succeed in the way that anyOf would seem to allow).

Comment: You may be missing things in your individual definitions. You should use `required` in each subschema next to any property definitions, to ensure that the property is actually present (properties listed in `properties` are optional by default). You may also want to include `{"not":{"required":["a property that should not be present"]}}` to ensure the properties from other definitions are not present at all.  But all these tools are documented for you at the links above.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, @ether gave me confidence in the right direction and just writing this up here with the final actual schema in case it helps someone else trying to "merge" or "blend" json objects together with allOf

The solution was

- definitions should only contain the "properties" and "required" parts
  finally construct the property options for our object with oneOf/allOf
- use oneOf(allOf(Aa),allOf(Ab),allOf(Ba),allOf(Bb)) pattern

  - allOf(oneOf(A,B),oneOf(a, b)) would also work, however it means that you cannot provide a title to explain to the user which allowed property combination they are using, which was useful to our solution)
- because we are using draft-4/7 we have to redefine the "properties" when combining the definitions to surface the inner definition properties. I understand this wouldn't be necessary with the later drafts

So the final working schema was this

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
    "$id": "https://blah.com/test",
    "title": "testSchema",
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "title":"Ba",
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/directTableReference"
                },
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/ObjectA"
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "schema":{},
                "tableName":{},
                "ObjectAName":{}
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
            "title":"Aa",
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/tableIdObject"
                },
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/ObjectA"
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "tableId":{},
                "ObjectAName":{}
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
            "title":"Bb",
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/directTableReference"
                },
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/ObjectB"
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "schema":{},
                "tableName":{},
                "ObjectBName":{}
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
            "title":"Ba",
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/tableIdObject"
                },
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/ObjectB"
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "tableId":{},
                "ObjectBName":{}
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "directTableReference": {
            "type":"object",
            "properties": {
                "schema": {
                    "title": "schema",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "tableName": {
                    "title": "tableName",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "schema",
                "tableName"
            ]
        },
        "tableIdObject": {
            "type":"object",
            "properties": {
                "tableId": {
                    "title": "tableIdObject",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "tableId"
            ]
        },
        "ObjectA": {
            "type":"object",
            "properties": {
                "ObjectAName": {
                    "title": "ObjectA",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "ObjectAName"
            ]
        },
        "ObjectB": {
            "type":"object",
            "properties": {
                "ObjectBName": {
                    "title": "ObjectB",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "ObjectBName"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

These are now valid

```json
{
    "schema":"blah",
    "tableName": "blah",
    "ObjectAName": "blah"
}
```

```json
{    
    "tableId": "blah",
    "ObjectAName": "blah",
}
```

```json
{    
    "tableId": "blah",
    "ObjectBName": "blah",
}
```

and these are not

```json
{    
    "tableId": "blah",
    "ObjectAName": "blah",
    "ObjectBName": "blah",
}
```

```json
{    
    "tableId": "blah",
    "blah":"blah"
}
```